# Formulario de symfony, campo de tipo FileType

Tags: php, symfony

Me encuentro con un problema al intentar subir imagenes al servidor utilizando un formulario de symfony de la siguiente manera:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($image)
        ->add('full', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Imagen', 'multiple' => true))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Guardar'))
        ->getForm();
```

Luego en el html:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}                        
{{ form_row(form.full) }}
{{ form_end(form)  }}
```

Al inspeccionar el html obtengo:

```
<form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                       
      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label required" for="form_full">Imagen</label>
            <input type="file" id="form_full" name="form[full][]" required="required" multiple="multiple" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]" class="btn-default btn">Guardar</button>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="vZjUzyZCsbsx5TmfWiljncIi1pPymfod_jezOOKgK_k" />
</form>
```

Cuando obtengo en el controlador el valor del fichero tengo esto:

[image: File]

Hasta aqui bien, pero en otros casos de otras imagenes con el mismo formato(jpeg), ocurre que obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve no reconoce el Mimetype que debería ser image/jpeg, y muestra que ocurre un error pero no dice cual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema resulta de que el error=1 significa que el fichero que se intenta subir es mayor que el límite establecido en el php.ini del servidor, cambiando este parámetro se soluciona:

php.ini:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=8M
```